# DataTables server-side filtering by objects in a Many to Many relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, datatables

I have a datatables.net DataTable in my app which shows all elements from a table (All entities of class `Action`). This class has an attribute which is a `List` of `Region`s mapped as `@ManyToMany` using Spring JPA, and I'd like to be able to filter by `Region`s all the data. So if I choose `Region`s A, B and D, only show those `Action`s that apply to at least one of them (For example if `Action` 1 applies to `Region`s B and C)

So the controller, which looks like this...

```
@JsonView(value={DataTablesOutput.View.class})
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/actions_datatable", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public DataTablesOutput<Action> getActions(@Valid DataTablesInput input, HttpServletRequest request) {
    DataTablesOutput<Action> actions_datatable = actionService.getActions(input);
    String[] regionIdsToFilter = request.getParameter("regionfilter").split("[,]");
    return actions_datatable;
}
```

This is my service

```
@Override
public DataTablesOutput<Action> getActions(DataTablesInput input) {
    return actionRepository.findAll(input);
}
```

And as a note, `ActionRepository` extends DataTablesRepository

receives the IDs for those regions I'd like to use to filter my actions, as well as the `DataTablesInput` object sent by the Javascript code.

What would be the best way to achieve this? It would be easier if the field I'm trying to filter was a simple String, or maybe even an object, but a list of them does look a bit harder for me.